# Exception when Controller's property is private or protected

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, fxml

I have this TextField in FXMLDocument.fxml:

```
<TextField fx:id="searchBox" onKeyPressed="#updateText">
   <StackPane.margin>
      <Insets left="60.0" right="30.0" top="50.0" />
   </StackPane.margin>
</TextField>
```

The FXML document (where the above code resides) has the controller class named FXMLDocumentController.java. Inside this, I have the following code:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController {

    public TextField searchBox;

    @FXML
    public void updateText (KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println(searchBox.getText());
    }
}
```

Note that the `searchBox` property is `public`. When I set it to `private`, my code throws an Exception at runtime. I have seen people specifying the "event bounded property" as `private` in Stack Overflow answers ([here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067893/how-do-i-get-an-element-in-javafx-using-an-id%22this%22)). Seeing those answers, I assume that specifying a property as `private` should not give any error. What's wrong with my code then?

Comment: This question is a duplicate. Thanks to James_D for pointing out :) The original post solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Use @FXML Annotation over your TextField searchBox. See below code:-

```
public class FXMLDocumentController {

        @FXML
        private TextField searchBox;

        @FXML
        public void updateText (KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println(searchBox.getText());
        }
    }
```